# Shortcut for searching all installed applications using debian/gnome

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

I'd like to create a shortcut to launch the "desktop search" application ("Applications" -> "Accessories" -> "Desktop Search") in debian/gnome.  Does this shortcut exist (or can it be created) in debian / gnome? Furthermore, to create more shortcuts like this, how can I find the name of any application which I can find by clicking "Applications" and browsing the graphical UI for the applications (e.g. the terminal command `google-chrome` will open chrome's GUI; I can also find chrome by going to "Applications" -> "Internet" -> "Google Chrome")?

I've tried a few google queries (e.g. "terminal command for desktop search"), but I think the problem is that I don't know what to query to find this information.

Comment: What version of gnome are you using? btw, I think a quick google query would solve that.

Comment: gnome-session 3.4.2.1

Comment: And pressing the *super* key doesn't help? What were you exactly tring to say with *how can I find the name of the application (e.g. google-chrome will open chrome in the terminal)*???? Could you please elaborate more? What have you tried so far? why did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Most linux desktops, by convention, use something called [**launchers**](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html), which are files with a `.desktop` extension and they're analogous to Windows' `.lnk` shortcuts, but more powerful. They're what you see in your application menus.

A launcher is just a small text file that contains paths to resources as: an icon, a title, a description and an **executable command line** that is just the absolute path to the actual application, among other features. Now, your desktop manager (say GNOME, XFCE, KDE, etc.) reads the instructions written on that file to show you information about that app, and when you click on it, it just executes the **command line** that the launcher file contains.

The actual executable file may be inside one of the common binary directories, `/usr/bin`, for example. Shell or terminal emulators look for binaries on these directories, that's why you can call `google-chrome` from a command line and Google Chrome will open, chances are that if you navigate to `/usr/bin` you'll find a symlink to the executable.

You can know where that executable is located by opening any `launcher` file on any plain text editor and by looking for the [`exec`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) key.

You can find (almost) all of the launchers you see on your menus inside the `/usr/share/applications` directory of your system, you can also find them inside the `~/.local/share/applications` directory inside your home directory.

And as far as I know, many desktop's (GNOME included) keybinds actually execute a **command line** to call the app the key was bound to, so you may first look into your `launchers` to see the actual command that is executed when such launcher is clicked, or you can look into your binaries folders (be careful here) for available binaries.

Many applications that were actually made to be available to be called from **launchers**, provide them along with their executables in the packages you download (like from the Ubuntu Software Center) and they're automatically installed into the predefined applications folders, so if an app doesn't come with a launcher it's most likely that it isn't intended to be called from one; though launchers provide an option to call text-only executables inside terminal emulators, but you can find more about it on the [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) pages.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I feel a lot more in the light now about what's going on when I click on a launcher in the GUI.  However, I was unable to find where the launcher is located for this specific application.  As an alternative, I downloaded gnome-do and made a custom shortcut to launch this program.